# Database scheme design for complex movie system

Tags: database-design, normalization, erd

I'm creating a complex app for cinemas including frontend and reservation system. I struggle with a DB scheme and this is a worst part for me, I was never good in designing DB's.

Easily said it's a classic cinema ticket system, nothing less nothing more.

I thought about doing code-first approach, therefore I'm not using Foreign-keys but List

I've came up with something like this, could you please give me some recommendations.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First things that strike me are:

- Your Movie table needs further Normalisation - holding lists of anything in a single field (actors) is a really Bad Idea.
- You might want to have a "master" table of Genres and join it to Movies in an n:m relationship - a Movie *can* cross genre boundaries.

My suggestions would be to break out **pen and paper** and *try* it!

Use one sheet for each table and work through each or your processes and see if the data holds together as you expect and that you can "get at" all the data in the way you think you should be able to.

Comment: Second vote on not using a list in a column. I did that many years ago and it was frustrating for everyone involved and does not work well (compatibility with tools, accessibility of dat). Stick with a FK relationship